# Reading an on premise file share from Java based azure web app

Tags: java, azure-web-app-service, fileshare

I have a java based azure web app which is trying to connect to an on premise file share and read a file from there. If I try locally its connecting with my ID. but when I am hosting it in the server its giving **Access denied** error.

I cannot alter the permissions in the file share and set to everyone. How can I read the file by providing the ID or impersonation?

I have tried with below userauthenticator but is not working in the hosting environemt.

```
UserAuthenticator auth = new StaticUserAuthenticator(domain, userName, password);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its auth issue perhaps issue may be due to App service as PAAS offering and have port restriction documented here:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#restricted-outgoing-ports

File share uses port 445 / 139 which is restricted to use with App services.